# Should I raise an issue when I see that a user's profile is inaccurate?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I know of several profile pages that are either misleading or contain outright lies.

For instance, *"I was a technical advisor to the President of the United States"*; *"I lead microprogramming for a major US business"*; or *"I have taught many programming languages to students from junior to post-graduate"*.

Should I do anything about them?

Comment: Unrelated, why is the first line of my question rendered in a smaller font than the second?

Comment: Bother to show some evidence or at least anonymized example? Otherwise that didn't happen. (Applies for your comment as well).

Comment: What does 'inaccurate' mean?  i.e. what level of inaccuracy are we talking about here?  Are you refuting users' claims of being God's gift to programming and that they invented all modern language, single-handedly? 
 Or are you identifying that accounts do not include social security number, date of birth, and mother's maiden name as factual information?  'Inaccurate' can mean quite a wide range of things.

Comment: Users are given a lot of free rein in their profiles but they must stick to the be nice policy. If they're abusing it, then sure, let the mods know. If they're just being inaccurate - that's on them... Why worry yourself?

Comment: @JonC: We can be at our nicest when we are lying. I have added some imaginary examples to my question, but I'm sure you can invent your own?

Comment: @Michael: If you read the body of my question then I think it will be clear to you.

Comment: @Borodin _"but I'm sure you can invent your own?"_ I've got a lively fantasy, but why should I bother about _virtual things_ (unless these are sophisticated math problems)?

Comment: Who really cares? I mean really. Who is this going to affect. The only situation I could see arising (far-fetched at that) would be for someone to get an interview request based on their profile, in which case they would eventually be found out, and the impact would be completely on themselves. Ultimately there is no guarantee that any information in any profile is true, nor is there any requirement or suggestion to the user that they should be truthful.

Comment: @user: I have been asked for examples, and have also been chastised for "outing" specific users. If you can think of a way to weave between the two then please advise me!

Comment: @Tiny: If that's your point of view then so be it: we can all lie our heads off in our profiles, and it's for other people to smoke us out if they wish to. My question is whether that's as it is, or as it should be? Personally, I would prefer to see some integrity and honesty, but maybe it's just a jokers' playground?

Comment: It is as it always has been and will be for the foreseeable future (anecdotal remark based on previous experiences on the metas). Stack Overflow has no interest in policing users profiles beyond the be nice policy.

Comment: @Borodin re: "jokers playground" in your comment edit: Ultimately this is a community oriented site. The community at large determines what this site is through action... and discussion, but mostly action. You are no more authorized to push your individual will on anyone else than they are to push their individual will on you. If you want to see a change in some aspect of the site, you have to consistently nag and poke and prod the community in the direction you want to see the community move in. Either you fail, or you succeed, but you can't expect anything to change overnight.

Comment: @Tiny: I'm reasonably aware of the way things *are*, but with the `discussion` tag I was hoping to discover what people thought may be more ideal. I shall not stop asking questions of *Meta* until I understand and can steer past the endless and obtuse *"why are you asking?"* and *"what evidence do you have?"* commentary.

Comment: I agree that the initial meta reaction to some of your recent posts has been less than ideal. There are a multitude of anecdotal remarks I could make in that regard, but that would be a much longer discussion than would be appropriate for this comment section. Don't get me wrong, I would never want to be a part of "silencing dissent" or any other such behavior, I personally just don't see there being any benefit to policing profiles. I don't think implementing policy would fix the problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: @Borodin _"and have also been chastised for "outing" specific users"_ That's why I said ***anonymized*** in my comment. You shouldn't drag attention to specific user accounts, when asking a generalized question for a potential course of action. I'm myself certainly not _lying_ at any point of my profile statement BTW.

Comment: do we draw the line on just the "About me" section or are you suggesting the entire profile has to be truthful? does that mean i can no longer have my location as *"Rathror Estate, Lucaria"* because i don't want people to know where i live in real life? does that mean i have to start using my real name for my display name instead of *"Memor-X"*? to be honest none of the examples you posted in the question would influence my view on someone's question or answer or how i vote on it

Comment: @Tiny: I just put fifteen minutes into writing a response. I'm travelling and working on my tablet. Being what it is, the *Stack Overflow* app threw it away, and as it's 01:39am I'm going to dozenow. I'm sorry that you'll never read my thoughts.

Comment: @Memo: I'm out for tonight. Please vote to reopen my question if you want to discuss this.

Comment: @jonc: You know that your diamond will earn you undeserved up votes, right?

Comment: @Borodin _"I'm out for tonight ..."_ Hope your hangover isn't too bad tomorrow. Merry X-Mas then.

Comment: Who are you to call any up or down-votes on this site or in this question undeserved? How do you know how or why people voted the way they did? Consider that his diamond most likely has been earned because of good judgement, both of subject and of politics (convincing people that his views are correct).

Comment: The question is, does it really matter? I'm not really Bugs Bunny and Jon isn't really a ninja puppy, wait maybe they are? I don't know. Ima report this...none of you can be trusted. BACK TO THE BASEMENT I GO!

Comment: @Bugs you're just saying that to fool Elmer Fudd - you cunning wabbit you :) Anyway... time for my walkies...

Comment: @Borodin This might come off as a surprise to you, but other humans have a brain too, and are able to choose how/what they upvote based on the content of said post, rather than its poster. Yes, things you don't agree with can be right.

Comment: [interviewer] "Hmm. technical advisor to President Trump.....  OK, next!"

Answer (score 37):

No, you shouldn't, for multiple reasons.

It's not even that pretty much nobody cares that someone is lying in their profile, it's that we are not equipped to handle verifying that information. Pretty much no service does. Facebook has exponentially more employees than we do and not even *they* verify the accuracy of information you put in your profile there. It's a fairly pointless endeavor that will only result in a lot of wasted time for no gain at all.

But even if we *were* interested in attempting to verify that information, there are other considerations...

- Some poeple include information as a joke, not actually intending to imply it's true. Sarcasm is hard to read, and it's hard to draw a line between jokingly claiming you work somewhere and actually claiming you work somewhere.
- Some people include information without knowing what it actually means. Using work experience as an example again, tons of users list "Stack Overflow" in their work experience even though they're only users.
- Some information simply cannot be verified, no matter how hard you try. Companies shut down, information gets lost, etc. Are we simply going to call people blatant liars because we can't find information to verify their claims? Don't think so.

---

As an aside, we have had people write into our support desk demanding we remove information from user profiles because they claimed to work at Such and Such Company, LLC and they've never heard of the person before. We decline to take action for all of those, for the very reasons outlined above. Our standard response is that employment verification exists for exactly that reason. If they don't actually work somewhere, then a short phone call to the company will reveal that if they're actually courageous enough to include a lie on their resume. That tends not to go over well with hiring managers.